# Trouble positioning TikZ node

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

My code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (0,0) {$M = \frac{A+B}{C \times D} + F + G$};
    \draw[thick, red, ->] (-0.5,0.5) -- (-.35,2);
    \draw[thick, red, ->] (0,0.5) -- (-.15,2);
    \draw[thick, ->] (0.7,-0.25) -- (1,-2);
    \draw[thick, ->] (1.3,-0.25) -- (1.1,-2);
    \node[red, ellipse,draw] (-.2,2.5) {method 1};
    \node[ellipse,draw] (1.1,-2.5) {method 2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And the result is

[image]

The result I want is

[image]

I'm not sure why the nodes aren't positioning correctly, because I think the coordinates given are right. If someone could help (and even better, explain) that'd be great.

**Bonus question**: How do you make it so just the node outline and not the text is red?

Thanks!

Comment: you are missing the `at` before the coordinates

Comment: @percusse, wow, I can't believe I made that mistake! =) Post that as an answer and I will accept it. (I think I'll also add something else to my question, first.) Thank you so much!

Comment: Use `draw=red` instead of `red, draw, ...`. Text will stay black.

Comment: @Alenanno, thanks so much! If you or percusse write an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first question is just a typo, that is, `at` keyword was missing before the coordinates so it was understood as the name of the node. The bonus question is actually comes to the fact that when a standalone color is given it sets some kind of a generic `\pgf....@current@color@....` for everything (behind the scenes it modifies the color `.` using the `xcolor` syntax)

A more selective color syntax is using the dedicated key in the path declaration such as

```
\draw[draw=red,text=blue] ...
```

That only modifies the specific property.

Comment: @heather my pleasure